# ScalaTest+Play compatibility with ScalaTest 3.0.1 and Play 2.5.12

Tags: scala, playframework, scalatest

I'm using Play 2.5.12, and in other parts of our project, we're using ScalaTest 3.0.1.

[According to the Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaTestingWithScalaTest), there is a glue library ScalaTest+Play to enable end-to-end testing of Play apps with ScalaTest:

> You do not need to add ScalaTest to your build explicitly. The proper version of ScalaTest will be brought in automatically as a transitive dependency of ScalaTest + Play. You will, however, need to select a version of ScalaTest + Play that matches your Play version. You can do so by checking the Versions, Versions, Versions page for ScalaTest + Play.

That [Versions, Versions, Versions](http://www.scalatest.org/plus/play/versions) page lists ScalaTest+Play versions up to 1.4.0, supporting ScalaTest 2.2.x and Play 2.4.x. The Play documentation however suggests that a newer ScalaTest+Play 1.5.0 version works with Play 2.5.x. It certainly exists, but I can't tell which version of ScalaTest it's using; it would seem not one that supports ScalaTest features we use in other parts of our codebase.

- Is there a more up to date version of the Versions, Versions, Versions page?
- Is there a version of ScalaTest+Play that works with Play 2.5.x and ScalaTest 3.0.x?

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the github of ScalaTest + Play, you can see that version 2.0.0 of the project uses Play 2.5.x and ScalaTest 3.0.x:
https://github.com/playframework/scalatestplus-play